# Transform by creating new columns from regex transformation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create new columns from a transformation of values within a column.

**Data**

```
location    stat            type    Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28   
NY          Low_Re_Num_De   AA      2       0       0       0   
NY          Low_Gr_Num_De   AA      2       2       2       6   
NY          Low_Re_Num_De   BB      0       0       0       0   
NY          Low_Gr_Num_De   BB      0       0       2       4   
NY          Low_Re_Num_De   DD      0       2       4       4   
NY          Low_Gr_Num_De   DD      2       2       4       8   
NY          Low_Re_Num_De   SS      0       0       0       0   
NY          Low_Gr_Num_De   SS      0       0       0       2   
CA          Med_Re_Num_De   AA      0       4       0       0   
CA          Med_Gr_Num_De   AA      2       0       0       0   
CA          Med_Re_Num_De   BB      0       2       0       0   
CA          Med_Gr_Num_De   BB      0       0       0       2   
CA          Med_Re_Num_De   DD      0       6       0       0   
CA          Med_Gr_Num_De   DD      2       0       0       0   
CA          Med_Re_Num_De   SS      0       2       0       0   
CA          Med_Gr_Num_De   SS      0       0       0       0
```

**Desired**

```
location    range   stat    type    Q1 28   Q2 28   Q3 28   Q4 28
NY          Low     Re      AA      2       0       0       0
NY          Low     Gr      AA      2       2       2       6
NY          Low     Re      BB      0       0       0       0
NY          Low     Gr      BB      0       0       2       4
NY          Low     Re      DD      0       2       4       4
NY          Low     Gr      DD      2       2       4       8
NY          Low     Re      SS      0       0       0       0
NY          Low     Gr      SS      0       0       0       2
CA          Med     Re      AA      0       4       0       0
CA          Med     Gr      AA      2       0       0       0
CA          Med     Re      BB      0       2       0       0
CA          Med     Gr      BB      0       0       0       2
CA          Med     Re      DD      0       6       0       0
CA          Med     Gr      DD      2       0       0       0
CA          Med     Re      SS      0       2       0       0
CA          Med     Gr      SS      0       0       0       0
```

**Doing**

```
df['range'] = df['stat'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
```

However, this fails to create the second column.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for splitted Series, for second column use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and for get lists in `Series` use indexing `str[0]` and `str[1]`:

```
s = df['stat'].str.split('_')
df.insert(1, 'range', s.str[0])
df['stat'] = s.str[1]

print (df)
   location range stat type  Q1 28  Q2 28  Q3 28  Q4 28
0        NY   Low   Re   AA      2      0      0      0
1        NY   Low   Gr   AA      2      2      2      6
2        NY   Low   Re   BB      0      0      0      0
3        NY   Low   Gr   BB      0      0      2      4
4        NY   Low   Re   DD      0      2      4      4
5        NY   Low   Gr   DD      2      2      4      8
6        NY   Low   Re   SS      0      0      0      0
7        NY   Low   Gr   SS      0      0      0      2
8        CA   Med   Re   AA      0      4      0      0
9        CA   Med   Gr   AA      2      0      0      0
10       CA   Med   Re   BB      0      2      0      0
11       CA   Med   Gr   BB      0      0      0      2
12       CA   Med   Re   DD      0      6      0      0
13       CA   Med   Gr   DD      2      0      0      0
14       CA   Med   Re   SS      0      2      0      0
15       CA   Med   Gr   SS      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: Your answering speed is insane.